# Serializable and Synchronization

Tags: c#, serialization, synchronization

I have a small class what I made thread safe with the [Synchronization] attribute, it also implements the ContextBoundObject interface. I'd like to make this class [Serializable]. The code compiles but I receive an

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Remoting cannot find field '__identity' on type 'System.MarshalByRefObject'
```

exception. I knew that classes marked with [Synchronization] are accessed through some 'remote' proxy but I hoped the default serialization mechanism will work.

This is a small app, the class is just an in-memory sequence (integer id) generator so no real remoting is done. I guess I can synchronize by other means (lock keyword) but I'd like to know what is the standard solution for this problem.

**Update:** at the end I abandoned the [Synchronization] attribute in order to use the basic serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just using the Serializable attribute, you can implement the ISerializable interface.

You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx

Basically you have to implement one method - GetObjectData - and a constructor with a similar signature.

Answer (score 0):

Mark any property that shouldn't be serialized as `[NonSerialized]`.

Also look at "custom serialization". In addition to marking the class as `[Serializable]`, you'll need to implement `ISerialiable` and add a custom constructor, thus:

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo : ISerializable
{
  // custom deserialization constructor]
  public Foo( SerializationInfo info , StreamingContext context )
  {
    //Get the values from info and assign them to the appropriate properties
  }

  public void GetObjectData( SerializationInfo info , StreamingContext context )
  {
    // populate info with appropriate key/value pairs.
    // Don't forget to explicitly serialize/deserialize and contained complex objects/structures
  }

}
```